# simultaneously fit multiple data sets with some shared parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, curve-fitting

I have multiple data sets with independent vectors x, and dependent vectors y.
I would like to fit each data set with this function:

> T*(x.^-12 - x.^-m)

Where T, m are fit parameters that I would like to find. 
the constraint is that **T should have the same value for all fits, and m can be different in each fit**.

What is the best way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: can someone tell me why I get no answers? what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this code that does exactly what I wanted
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40613-multiple-curve-fitting-with-common-parameters-using-nlinfit